# Chef - difference between knife.rb and solo.rb

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, devops

When I run `chef-solo` without specifying the `-c solo.rb` parameter, it throws a warning

```
[2015-06-25T14:53:04-04:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2015-06-25T14:53:04-04:00] WARN: Did not find config file: /etc/chef/solo.rb, using command line options.
[2015-06-25T14:53:04-04:00] WARN: *****************************************
```

Presumably it's looking for a system `solo.rb` file because I didn't specify one explicitly.

I also have a `.chef/knife.rb` file available.

1. What's the difference between the `solo.rb` and `knife.rb` files? They seem to have the exact same info defined - `cookbook_path`, `file_cache_path`, `log_level`, etc.. - so it seems redundant
2. Does `chef-solo` ever look for and use my `knife.rb` file? It's looking all over the place for a `solo.rb` file, and was wondering if it ever falls back to searching the default `.chef/knife.rb` file.

Thanks!

Comment: The knife.rb file is used for the knife command. Knife is an admin tool for controlling a chef server, so completely unrelated to chef solo.

Comment: gotcha. So if I have the exact same content in both can I consolidate everything into my `knife.rb` file and then point `chef-solo` to just use the `knife.rb` file as a config file? Or is that bad practice?

Comment: That will work. But chef solo is getting a bit out of date. Check out the "local mode" capability now in chef client. (see the -z option). Uses an embedded instance of chef server.

Comment: To get rid of the warning, specify the full path for solo.rb if you are indeed passing the `-c` flag